how to replace a value conditional on another variable is missing
I am trying to replace the variable in the mtcars data set I created with 1 when gear == NA. I am getting an error when running the following, how do you replace evaluating if a variable takes NA?
summary(mtcars)
mtcars$new <- NA
mtcars$new[mtcars$gear == NA] <- 1
print(mtcars$new)


well by default there are no NAs in mtcars$gear. but instead of mtcars$gear == NA you would need mtcars$gear %in% NA or better is.na(mtcars$gear)

What's the error message?

Indeed, there is no NA value in mtcars$gear. However, if you need to replace NA values in a dataset, here is one way to do it:
df <- data.frame(
  item = c("A","B","C","D","E","F"),
  qty = c(5,NA,2,6,4,NA)
)

print(df)

  item qty
1    A   5
2    B  NA
3    C   2
4    D   6
5    E   4
6    F  NA

# replace NA in qty with 1
df$qty <- ifelse(is.na(df$qty),1,df$qty)

print(df)

  item qty
1    A   5
2    B   1
3    C   2
4    D   6
5    E   4
6    F   1

I hope it helps!
